# select * for xml path is omitting columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

`select * from ViewWhatever for xml path ('node')` returns a well-formed xml document, but wherever there are NULL entries columns, the element for that column is missing.

How can I stop this from happening?

e.g.

```
Id | Date       | Name
 1   NULL         Bill
 2   2020-01-01   Bob
```

returns

```
<node>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Bill</Name>
</node>
<node>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Date>2020-01-01...</Date>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
</node>
```

But I want it to be:

```
<node>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Date /> // This node should exist!
    <Name>Bill</Name>
</node>
<node>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Date>2020-01-01...</Date>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
</node>
```

Comment: [xsinil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/generate-elements-for-null-values-with-the-xsinil-parameter?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: I just found an answer that mentioned that but no place to put it

Comment: ok found out how to do it and now it's adding a weird namespace but at least it's progress

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name usually do, oversight on my behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ELEMENTS XSINIL;
[You can see how to do that here](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/including-null-columns-empty-elements-125474.aspx)

Comment: I used it successfully but now for some reason parsing the xml on the client-side is taking AGES compared to if this namespace isn't included :(

Comment: have a look at the execution plan of your sql query to see if you get any bottlenecks there, otherwise performance would be something else, I doubt that XSINIL as a utility creates much of an overhead in performance

Comment: The query is super quick, it's the client-end processing (in excel vba!!) - it was working very quickly before but now seems to take ages to process less than 100 rows. I'm trying to use something that processes sets of nodes now instead one at a time...

Comment: you can look into batch processing on threads to improve that possibly